# how to make url slug like Quora does using Yii framework ?

Tags: php, url, yii, slug

Using Quora has made me wonder how they do their slug like thes : quora.com/topics-slugs , quora.com/questions-slug or quora.com/usernames-slug.

Actually i am developing an application with yii framework and i want to have a slugs like quora does?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with rewrite rules. A rule like this in your config file:

```
'controller/<slug:[\w\-]+>'=>'controller/view',
```

will take a URL like this:

```
controller/my-slug
```

and it will redirect to the actionView() in your Controller, and pass the slug ("my-slug") in as a $_GET variable. With that rewrite rule you now call $_GET['slug'] and it will return "my-slug" from the url.

I have a "slug" row as a primary key so then I just query the DB for $_GET['slug'] in my actionView() and I get the correct record based on the URL. Works like a charm. Good luck!

UPDATE
To get rid of the controller prefix in addition to using a slug, you will probably need one large table to keep track of all url slugs (to prevent duplicates). If you have that, then you could do a couple of different things:

1 Override [onBeginRequest](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/CApplication#onBeginRequest-detail) to do a lookup on the master slug table to figure out which Controller to call.
2. Use a master rewrite to a single ActionIndex in the SiteController, and in that action look up the slug in the master table to figure out which controller/action to send the user to. The rewrite rule would look something like this:

```
'<slug:[\w\-]+>'=>'site/index',
```

Comment: Thanks for help , But Maybe i didn't explain what i mean very well. what i meant is in quora.com you will see all the page including (topic, question and user name) has slug after the domain and there is no param infront of the slug to call the controller and action examples for topic  http://www.quora.com/StackOverflow and for question http://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-Quora-implement-a-reputation-system-a-la-StackOverflow  so how does request proceed ?

Comment: I tried to add a little more info to point you in the right direction. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

1. Handle any special characters you wanna use (Umlauts for example)
2. Remove any non-alpha-numeric-characters that are left
3. handle white spaces

Something like that for example:

```
function _getSlugFromName($name){
   return preg_replace('#[\s]+#','-',preg_replace('#[^\d\w -]*#','',str_replace(array('ä','ü','ö','ß'),array('ae','ue','oe','ss'),html_entity_decode(mb_strtolower(trim($name),'UTF-8'),ENT_COMPAT,'UTF-8'))));
}
```

Comment: Thank u, But Maybe i didn't explain what i mean very well. what i meant is in quora.com you will see all the page including (topic, question and user name) has slug after the domain and there is no param infront of the slug to call the controller and action examples for topic  http://www.quora.com/StackOverflow and for question http://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-Quora-implement-a-reputation-system-a-la-StackOverflow  so how does request proceed ?

Answer (score 1):

This may help you: [dburlmanager](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/dburlmanager)

> Provides dynamic database-based URL rules.
>   Dynamic URL rules based on database (pretty permalinks or friendly URLs)
>
> These dynamic rules are like Wordpress' "pretty permalinks" or "friendly URLs". You do not have to have the controller name (or ID) on the URL: this extension can handle the request URI and route it to the correct controller.